# How can I get the image URL from a LinkedIn post using the Post API?

Tags: javascript, typescript, linkedin-api

I am trying to get the URL of all the media inside of an organization post but all I can get is the image URN. I don't want to do another request to get the image but rather get the Posts information and the URL on the same call.

I tried to use the Posts API as the UGC Post API is currently marked as Legacy.

```
let testresp = await axios.get(https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?q=author&author=`urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A${LinkedInHelpers.URNtoID(orgsRes.data.elements[0].organizationalTarget)}`&fields=id,content:(media), {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken.data.access_token}`,
                'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
                'LinkedIn-Version': '202301'
            }
        })
```

I also tried to use the `~` decorator to get extra data on the Media but it returns an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please try making the get request add this address instead [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/${postId}](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/$%7BpostId%7D)

Try this :

```
axios.get(`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/${postId}`, { headers })
  .then((res) => {
    const imgUrl = res.data.media_url;
    console.log(imgUrl);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

Comment: When using this Endpoint the response says `not enough permissions to access field media~ for GET-author /posts` when projecting `media~`. What permisions are needed for this Endpoint?

Comment: That's normal, did you have an access_token from linkedin, if not
You will have to get the access_token to authorize the request, follow the steps in the LinkedIn Developer documentation to create a new app and get a access_token. 
Then you can make a  GET request at 

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/{post_id}

Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
replace the value of post_id and acess_token by urs...

Comment: I do have the access_token but it seems like they haven't implemented a way to get the post images URL from the Post API yet. Or at least thats what I understand from the change log on the deprecation of UGC Post when the say some extended fields are going to be added in the future. Anyways thank you very much for your help!